# SonarQube Home page does not expose login functionality

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Installed SonarQube 6.0

The Home page does not appear to have a place to log in.

In addition to the header "Home" there is an informational box, "Welcome to SonarQube Dashboard" with several links that redirect me to SonarSource's website.  Additionally, there are a couple of tables entitled "Projects", but because I'm just getting started, there are no projects.

I can't find anyplace that even hints at allowing me to log in.  I suspect that if I could log in, I might be able to start configuring.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Update: Image of my Sonar home page:
[image: Sonar Home Page Image]

Note: no login button, no settings, nothing on "menu bar" portion of window. (as shown in image above)

Comment: Have your tried in different browsers?

Comment: Good catch!  It has no "menu bar" in IE 10, but does in Chrome 52.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm using IE 11 and it's fine. Don't have an IE 10 around to test if IE 10 is also an issue for us.

Answer (score 2):

There's a log in button in the top right corner of the home page.
See the highlighted section in the image:
[image: SonarQube 6.0 Home Dashboard]

Answer (score 2):

IE10 is not anymore supported by SonarQube. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements